# Log all HTTP responses in Express

Tags: node.js, http, express

What's the best approach to log all HTTP responses in Express?

The only way I was able to got it working was monkey patching the `end` event.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var rEnd = res.end;

  res.end = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log(chunk.toString('utf8');
    rEnd.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  next();
});
```

I'm interested in a more elegant solution, for example using the `finish` event, but I'm unable to access the response message on this context.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.on('finish', function() {
    // console.log(?);
  });

  next();
});
```

Comment: Inside the `finish` event function you can, e.g., use `res.getHeaders()` and `res.statusCode` to get the response data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used [express-winston](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston) which provides a middleware for request and error logging.

```
import express from 'express'
import winston from 'winston'
import expressWinston from 'express-winston'
import routes from './routes'

const app = express()

// Log the whole request and response body
expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body')
expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body')

// Logger makes sense before the router
app.use(expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      json: true,
      colorize: true
    })
  ]
}))

// Now we can tell the app to use our routing code
app.use(routes);

// Error logger makes sense after the router
app.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      json: true,
      colorize: true
    })
  ]
}))

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

With 'Morgan' and 'Rotating File Stream', you can both log the transactions(request and response) and store it in an interval.

```
var express= require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//we get an instance of express  
var app = express();
var rfs = require('rotating-file-stream');
var morgan = require('morgan');
//log file rotation
var logDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'log')
// ensure log directory exists 
fs.existsSync(logDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory)
// create a rotating write stream 
var accessLogStream = rfs('access.log', {
  interval: '1d', // rotate daily 
  path: logDirectory
});
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
```

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of packages which logs both response and request.

The most common is [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan), check it out.

Most of the packages simply provide a middleware which has to be added to your app object using `app.use` method.

Comment: It isn't possible to log the HTTP parameters with morgan